# Captcha seems to pop up at every edit

Tags: discussion

I am getting a captcha each time I edit or do anything here - it is pretty annoying. Is the captcha set up differently here?

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a mobile device? There was a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63556/get-captcha-every-time-when-im-on-mobile) about this happening on mobile devices; supposedly a fix was pushed out yesterday but we're a couple of point releases behind, so we might not have it yet, or the fix might be bad

Comment: No I am on a Windows PC using Google Chrome browser (yes OK shoot me).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to happen to me when I do edits in quick succession.

Comment: It's supposed to pop up then, but it shouldn't happen every time you interact with the site

Comment: @Michael I know I was just saying it because it was my only idea.